# ¿Còmo puedo crear una variable con valores separados por comas al recorrer un objeto?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

Desde mi `View` mando un modelo a mi `controller` el cual es una lista de valores o mas bien una lista de `checkbox`. De esa lista necesito recorrer una propiedad del modelo con nombre "Cod" y por cada valor que encuentre en esa propiedad que me genere una variable string o cualquier otro tipo para ir almacenando cada valor que encontró separado por comas. Ejemplo:

Mi `controller`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(MiModelo model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        for (int i = 0; i < model.ModeloList.Count(); i++)
        {
            var Lista = string.Join(",", model.ModeloList[i].Cod);
        }

        // Logic

        return View();
    }
```

Mi `model`

```
public class MiModelo 
{
    public MiModelo ()
    {
        this.ModeloLista = new List<Modelo>();
    }

    public List<Modelo> ModeloLista { get; set; }

    public class Modelo
    {
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public int Suc{ get; set; }
        public int Cod{ get; set; }
        public string Nom{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

En rigor en la variable Lista de la linea `var Lista = string.Join(",", model.ModeloList[i].Cod);` debería ir agregando o concatenando todos los valores que va encontrando, pero de la forma en que tengo esa parte de la lógica no me funciona.

al revisar la variable `Lista` solo me va guardando un valor, pero debería ir guardándome n valores como n sea el numero de lista que encuentre. Ejemplo:

"1,2,3,4,5,...."  Esto seria a lo que quiero llegar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías resolver eso con Linq. Por ejemplo:

```
string.Join(",", model.ModeloList.Select(m => m.Cod.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Ver: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mq1eFy

Comment: Muchas gracias ! me sirvió un  montón

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que andas iterando la lista y creando la variable dentro del `for`, para solucionarlo debes sacar `var Lista` del `for`, o cambiar:

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.ModeloList.Count(); i++)
    var Lista = string.Join(",", model.ModeloList[i].Cod);
```

Por:

```
var lista = modelo.ModeloLista.Select(x => x.Cod.ToString()).ToList();
var finalString = string.Join(",", lista);
```

Luego de eso, si quieres ponerlo en tu `View`:

```
ViewBag.ListaDeString = finalString;
```

Y en la vista lo puedes mostrar:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListaDeString)
{
  <p>@item</p>
}
```

Recuerda hacer `using System.Linq;` para poder utilizar la función `Select`.